# What is lacking in my VBA code? Looking to have multiple checkboxes that when one is selected, it hides all other rows

Tags: vba, ms-word

Brand new to coding junk in VBA for Microsoft Word. I have a table with 12 rows and I want to place a standard content control checkbox next to each row, and when any given checkbox is checked, the other rows disappear.

Currently I've had good luck at this with purely text, but trying to bookmark to hide an entire row of a table only seems to work for the very first checkbox. (Sorry if my code is more complicated than it needs to be. I also skipped pasting all of the code since the other 10 lines are the same, so the final 12 `End If`s are necessary):

[image]

```vb
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim cc As ContentControl

For Each cc In ActiveDocument.ContentControls

If cc.Title = "impact" Then

    If cc.Checked = True Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bfganalytical").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("EA").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("fascia1").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("fascia2").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("grille1").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("grille2").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("shutter1").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("shutter2").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("liner").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("license").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("lamp1").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("lamp2").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("blank").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("impact").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("beamanalytical").Range.Font.Hidden = False
    Else: ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("impact").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bfganalytical").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("EA").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("fascia1").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("fascia2").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("grille1").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("grille2").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("shutter1").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("shutter2").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("liner").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("license").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("lamp1").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("lamp2").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("beamanalytical").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("blank").Range.Font.Hidden = False
    End If
    Exit Sub
Else: If cc.Title = "license" Then

    If cc.Checked = True Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("beamanalytical").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("impact").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("fascia1").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("fascia2").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("grille1").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("grille2").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("shutter1").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("shutter2").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("liner").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("license").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("lamp1").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("lamp2").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("blank2").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("blank3").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("EA").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bfganalytical").Range.Font.Hidden = False
    Else: ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("impact").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bfganalytical").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("EA").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("fascia1").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("fascia2").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("grille1").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("grille2").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("shutter1").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("shutter2").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("liner").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("license").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("lamp1").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("lamp2").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("beamanalytical").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("blank2").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("blank3").Range.Font.Hidden = False
    End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the content control Title is the same as the bookmark name you can try this simplified version of your code.

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)

  Dim cc As ContentControl

  For Each cc In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists(cc.Title) Then
      ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(cc.Title).Range.Font.Hidden = cc.Checked
    End If
  Next cc
End Sub
```

EDIT:
The issue you have with your original code is that it will only allow one row to be hidden.
To make your solution work you need to query the checked status of the corresponding content control for each bookmark. Your best option to achieve that is to ensure that the bookmark name matches either `cc.Title` or `cc.Tag`, otherwise you are back to complex and unwieldy code.

Comment: Thanks Tim. If my bookmarks were named differently, how would I go about this? I would figure the ActiveDocument.Bookmarks would be replacing 'cc.Title' with the bookmark name, and leaving the = cc.Checked?  Your code looks 100% simpler than my albatross

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need anything more complicated than:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal CCtrl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
With CCtrl
  If .Range.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
    If .Checked = True Then
      .Range.Tables(1).Range.Font.Hidden = True
      .Range.Rows(1).Range.Font.Hidden = False
    Else
      .Range.Tables(1).Range.Font.Hidden = False
    End If
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

Looping through all the content controls is quite unnecessary. You don't even need any titles or bookmarks.

Comment: What the heck. this is so easy. You condensed my code from like 200 lines down to 12. I have to stare at this to understand it's logic better (not familiar with 'With' command, and not sure why index of 1 is used in 'Tables/Rows'), but it worked. And I greatly appreciate your input

Comment: The 'With' simply means one doesn't have to insert 'CCtrl' on every line and makes it easier to understand how the items within the 'With' - 'End With' are related. The '1' in '.Range.Tables(1)' refers to the first (and only) table the content control is in. Similarly, The '1' in '.Range.Rows(1)' refers to the first (and only) row the content control is in.